# Show $J_2(x) = (2/x)J_1(x)-J_0(x)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

The Bessel function of the first kind and order $p$ is given by:
$$
J_{p}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\, \Gamma(n+p+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+p}
$$

I want to show that $J_2(x) = (2/x)J_1(x)-J_0(x)$. Here is what I have tried:

$$
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}J_1(x)-J_0(x) = 
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\, \Gamma(n+2)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+1} -
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\, \Gamma(n+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+2)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{-n}{\Gamma(n+2)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} 
$$

But I don't see how I could manipulate this expression to get:
$$
J_{2}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\, \Gamma(n+3)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+2}
$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use any identities of Bessel functions? Or do you have to prove this by the definition?

Comment: I am only allowed to use the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct in arriving at $$\frac{2}{x}J_1(x)-J_0(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{-n}{\Gamma(n+2)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}$$ The next thing to observe is that the entire sum is equal to zero when $n=0$ because of the $-n$ that appears in the numerator. Thus $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{-n}{\Gamma(n+2)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{-n}{\Gamma(n+2)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\left[\frac{-(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2(n+1)} \\ = 
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(-1)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)!}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+3)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+2}
 \\ =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+3)} \right]\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+2}$$ And you get your result.